# CouchDB instance server performance impact?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I'm toying with the idea of using a single server for multiple CouchDB instances to support various unrelated web apps built and hosted for clients.  I know I could successfully serve those apps via a single instance, but I'd prefer to isolate each to allow 100% independent administration since some client tech resources will surely want that access - but of course I do not want even a remote possibility they could impact other client's data or settings.

I'm particularly curious to know if I were to setup a several instances on a single box, if these instances could co-exist without severely impacting server resource availability.  Is there an upper limit on the number of instances to run side-by-side? I know storage will be a consideration, but whats the impact on other system resources for a moderately loaded CouchDB instance?  Does anybody have any real world experience running multiple production CouchDB instances on a single server that can share server impacts?

Comment: It's up to you to do you own benchmarks if you are really serious about it.

Comment: why not use virtual machines? That's the standard approach to separating servers from another and depending on what kind of virtualization you use doesn't need much more resources than several CouchDB instances on one machine.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [BigCouch](https://github.com/cloudant/bigcouch).